# Relationship between Clairaut's theorem and Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Is there a way to derive Clairaut's theorem from Fubini's theorem? It seems that the two are analogous in a way, one about the interchangeability of derivatives and the other about integrals.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem about partial derivatives is a pointwise statement; all you need is for the function $f: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ to be twice differentiable at a single point $a \in \Bbb{R}^n$. From this assumption alone, it will follow that all the second order partial derivatives exist and are equal.

Also, yes, there is a proof using Fubini's theorem (and the fundamental theorem of calculus), but for this I think one has to assume existence and continuity of the mixed partial derivatives in some open set $U$ containing $a$ (so that you can then apply Fubini's theorem). If we assume continuity of the mixed partials in an open set, then we can very easily apply Fubini's theorem even with the Riemann integral. I wouldn't be surprised if weaker hypotheses suffice for the argument to hold, but then the hypotheses made to ensure validity of FTC and Fubini's theorem would necessarily get more complicated (in which case, I think a direct proof of equality of mixed partials becomes much easier).

For example, this is an exercise in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, Problem $3$-$28$.